# Is it possible to pipe a bash formatted date to the AWS S3 CLI cp --include?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am using the AWS CLI to copy files from the S3 bucket and am using the --include --exclude parameters to select files only from certain dates. My goal is to download only the files from the previous week, and automate this process. I want to get the curent date minus one week from bash and pass this to --include and am wondering if this is possible.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you want to use `--include` and `--exclude`? These will select objects based on their Key (filename), so what is the format of your filenames? Or are you wanting to use the `LastModified` field to select which files to download based on their creation date rather than their filename? Also, have you considered simply using `aws s3 sync`, which will only download files not previously copied?

Comment: Hey, John. Thank you for your comment. I wanted to use code that looked like: aws s3 cp s3:my_bucket --exclude "*" --include "<current date - 7 days>*", but I think now that I am going about it the incorrect way and using aws s3 sync will be a better path forward. Thanks for your help.